# How to union two case statement columns

Tags: sql

I've created 2 case statements to pull data from a single table (it's been created as 2 separate case statements as I want to double count values and as a single case statement, it did not do this).

The 2 case statements have resulted in 2 new columns of data (case statement A and case statement B).  However, I'd like the 2 case statement values to be reported in a single column, so I'm trying to find a way to union these 2 columns together.

Here is my query as it stands.  I'm very new to SQL (just over a week!) so please excuse any silly syntax in my query.

```
select b.part_month, count(a.pay_code), sum(a.amount),
CASE
when a.pay_code like 'CC%' THEN 'Credit Card Payment'
when a.pay_code like 'DC%' then 'Debit Card Payment'
Else 'N/A'
End as Payment_Type,

CASE
when a.pay_code like '%IP%' then 'Internet Payment'
when a.pay_code like '%TT%' then 'Touchtone Payment'
Else 'N/A'
End as Payment_Type

from table_a A
inner join table_b B on A.form_ID = B.ID
where a.trans_type > 0
and b.st_id = 2

group by B.PART_MONTH,
CASE
when a.pay_code like 'CC%' THEN 'Credit Card Payment'
when a.pay_code like 'DC%' then 'Debit Card Payment'
Else 'N/A'
End,

CASE
when a.pay_code like '%IP%' then 'Internet Payment'
when a.pay_code like '%TT%' then 'Touchtone Payment'
Else 'N/A'
End
order by b.part_month asc;
```

Comment: Your case expression columns need different aliases.

Comment: OK I can do that, but how do I then union them together?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Giving you `CASE` statements aliases, then wrapping your query to `GROUP BY` the aliases.

Also combined your `CASE` statements, assuming this is what you wanted.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT b.part_month, 
    COUNT(a.pay_code) AS PayCodeCount,
    SUM(a.amount) AS AmountSum,
    CASE a.pay_code 
        WHEN 'CC%' THEN 'Credit Card Payment'
        WHEN 'DC%' THEN 'Debit Card Payment'
        WHEN '%IP%' THEN 'Internet Payment'
        WHEN '%TT%' THEN 'Touchtone Payment'
        ELSE 'N/A'
    END AS Payment_Type
    FROM table_a A
    INNER JOIN table_b B ON A.form_ID = B.ID
    WHERE a.trans_type > 0
    AND b.st_id = 2) Z
GROUP BY PART_MONTH, Payment_Type
ORDER BY part_month ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want:

```
select b.part_month, count(a.pay_code), sum(a.amount),
       (case when a.pay_code like 'CC%' then 'Credit Card Payment'
             when a.pay_code like 'DC%' then 'Debit Card Payment'
             when a.pay_code like '%IP%' then 'Internet Payment'
             when a.pay_code like '%TT%' then 'Touchtone Payment'
             else 'N/A'
        end) as Payment_Type
from table_a a inner join
     table_b b
     on a.form_ID = b.ID
where a.trans_type > 0 and b.st_id = 2
group by b.part_month,
         (case when a.pay_code like 'CC%' then 'Credit Card Payment'
               when a.pay_code like 'DC%' then 'Debit Card Payment'
               when a.pay_code like '%IP%' then 'Internet Payment'
               when a.pay_code like '%TT%' then 'Touchtone Payment'
               else 'N/A'
          end)
order by b.part_month asc;
```

Importantly:  some databases will allow you to use the alias in the `group by`, accepting `group by b.part_month, payment_type`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.  Gordon Linoff, I have tried your query but this gets me the results I had originally started with before splitting the case statement in 2.

The pay_code %IP% and %TT% can also match the CC% and DC% statements, and when it does, it doesn't count the IP or TT values.  However, I need to count all values where it matches %IP%, %TT%, CC% and DC%, even if that means double counting some rows of data.

So the values in the pay_code column might be 'DCIP', 'CCTT', 'CCIP', etc.  From those values, I want to know that there is 1 DC payment, 2 CC payments, 2 IP payments and 1 TT payment.

This is how my table ends up looking with the single case statement.  Note there are no Internet Payment or Touchtone Payment entries.

```
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
N/A
Credit Card Payment
Debit Card Payment
```

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is

```
Select * from (select b.part_month, count(a.pay_code), sum(a.amount),
CASE
when a.pay_code like '%IP%' then 'Internet Payment'
when a.pay_code like '%TT%' then 'Touchtone Payment'
Else 'N/A'
End as Payment_Type

from table_a A
inner join table_b B on A.form_ID = B.ID
where a.trans_type > 0
and b.st_id = 2

group by B.PART_MONTH,
CASE
when a.pay_code like '%IP%' then 'Internet Payment'
when a.pay_code like '%TT%' then 'Touchtone Payment'
Else 'N/A'
End

Union

select b.part_month, count(a.pay_code), sum(a.amount),
CASE
when a.pay_code like 'CC%' THEN 'Credit Card Payment'
when a.pay_code like 'DC%' then 'Debit Card Payment'
Else 'N/A'
End as Payment_Type

from table_a A
inner join table_b B on A.form_ID = B.ID
where a.trans_type > 0
and b.st_id = 2

group by B.PART_MONTH,
CASE
when a.pay_code like 'CC%' THEN 'Credit Card Payment'
when a.pay_code like 'DC%' then 'Debit Card Payment'
Else 'N/A'
End)

Order by 1,4;
```